# Easily extract data from string formatted a specific way

Tags: php, regex, string

What is an easy way to take a string that is formatted this way:

```
c:7|bn:99
```

and be able to use that string easily? So if I wanted to get the number that is behind the c:, How could I get that easily. Same, thing with the number behind bn:?

Comment: regex can help you achieve this

Comment: Is this always going to be the format of the string? letter:number|letter:number?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$arr = array();
$str = "c:7|bn:99";
$tmp1 = explode('|', $str);

foreach($tmp1 as $val)
{
   $tmp2 = explode(':', $val);
   $arr[$tmp2[0]] = $tmp2[1]; 
}

//print ur array
print_r($arr);

//accessing specifc value
echo $arr['c']." ".$arr['bn'];
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use `preg_match()` function or you could use `explode()` function twice (first with `|` delimiter and second with `:` delimiter).

Example #1:

```
<?php
if( preg_match( '/^c:(\d+)\|bn:(\d+)$/', $sString, $aMatches ) )
{
  print_r( $aMatches );
}
?>
```

Example #2:

```
<?php
$aPairs = explode('|', $sString ); // you have two elements in $aPairs
foreach( $aParis as $sPair )
{
  print_r( explode(':', $sPair ) );
}
?>
```

Comment: I like this answer, but note that [`split()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.split.php) is deprecated since PHP 5.3.0. Use [`explode()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$string = 'c:7|bn:99';
preg_match('/\Ac:([0-9]+)\|bn:([0-9]+)\z/', $string, $matches);
var_dump($matches);
```

Answer (score 0):

If `c` & `bn` are not dynamic:

```
var_dump(sscanf("c:7|bn:99","c:%d|bn:%d"));
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  int(7)
  [1]=>
  int(99)
}
```